# Who is user user2719?

Tags: discussion, users, profile-page, user-accounts

I know this isn't specifically related to this area but I was recently reading this question [here.](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13411/when-is-it-okay-to-have-blown-highlights-and-shadows)

There's a good answer by user2719. In the comments it's at Stan (who I remember). Does anyone know why he left?

I guess a more suitable questions is, how do you do that? Do you have to contact admin and/or ask to remove your profile? What is left behind?

(Sorry. I didn't mean on another's behalf.)

Say I wanted to request to remove your account? What happens then? I'm guessing there needs to be other's who agree? Is there a quota for agreers?

Comment: You're over-thinking this. SE is a company, they have employees that can do this, this would be the "they" I mentioned. This is not, however, _Survivor_, so you don't get to vote people off the island. Now, if you encounter an abusive user, you can flag or notify moderators to handle them.

Comment: Now, the moderators also need to agree with your assessment. We have tools available to help correct bad situations, user deletion would not be a first choice regardless.

Comment: I've been wondering why Stan dissappeared so abruptly too.  I always read his posts carefully because he had good things to say.  I hope he is OK.  I don't see why his profile couldn't have been kept around though.  Having a profile doesn't force you to participate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it would be appropriate for any of us to comment on the circumstances surrounding Stan leaving. However, I do hope your other questions are just idle curiosity rather than a desire of your own!

At any rate, any public declaration is sufficient to start the process. If the request is voluntary, there's usually a 24 hour grace period that starts and the user can cancel before that ends. The help center has [full details](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).

What happens to your stuff? Well, any votes you have cast get reversed and everything else is denormalized to your user number. The exception to the vote reversal is for really extensive users whose removal would create very large ripples, but that process is more complex and only done under particular circumstances.

Comment: OK, thanks. Can there also be requests from other people or can it only be self applied?

Comment: @BBking - Well, of course they can delete other people, but not usually at another user's request as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Sorry, who's "they"? Anyone can delete anyone? I've added to my question.

Comment: Moderators and certain Stack Exchange employees can delete accounts. **We never delete an account until we can prove that the request has come directly from the owner of the account.**